# If username / email already exists highlight the corresponding input field with mat-error message in mat-form-field(angular-material)

Tags: typescript, angular-material

`<mat-form-field> <mat-label>Username</mat-label> <input type="text" required matInput formControlName="username"> </mat-form-field>`
This is username template.

```
this.apiService.registerUser(user).subscribe(
  (res) => {
    this.toast.success({
      detail: 'Success',
      summary: res[0].message,
      duration: 5000,
    });
    this.reset();
  },
  (error) => {
    this.toast.error({
      detail: 'Error',
      summary: error.error.detail,
      duration: 5000,
    });
  }
);
```

This is the signup() with response of success and error message.Here I have used ng-angular-popup to display toast messages.

`My requirement is that If "username already exists" error popups hightlight the username mat-form-field with red border and mat-error showing "username already exists.Please choose a different username"